# TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of null in Angular2 Observable

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

### Error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of null

### Template calling the Observer.next (the problem)

```
import { NavService } from '../../providers/services/nav-service/nav-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ion-header',
  providers: [NavService],
  template: `
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>{{navService.getCurrentName()}}</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons start>
            <button (click)="navService.goHome()">
                <span primary showWhen="ios">Cancel</span>
                <ion-icon name="md-close" showWhen="android,windows"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
  `
})
```

### Service with Observable

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()

export class NavService {
private dismissObserver: any
public  dismiss: any

constructor (
    private authService:    AuthService,
    private platform:       Platform
) {
    this.dismissObserver = null;
    this.dismiss = Observable.create(observer => {
        this.dismissObserver = observer;
    });
}

public goHome():void {
    this.dismissObserver.next(true);
}
```

### app.ts with subscription

```
@Component({
    providers: [NavService]
})

export class MyApp {

  @ViewChild(Nav) navController: Nav
  constructor(
    public navService: NavService

) {
    this.initializeApp()
  }

 initializeApp() {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

        StatusBar.styleDefault()
        this.setRoot()
        this.navController.setRoot(HomePage);

        this.navService.dismiss.subscribe((event) => {
            console.log ("event", event);
            this.navController.setRoot(HomePage)
        })
    })
}

ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [])
```

Btw, I am using this "tutorial":

[Ionic2, inject NavController to Injectable Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833414/ionic2-inject-navcontroller-to-injectable-service)

Comment: OK let me provide code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code in `Observable.create` where you assign `dismissObserver` is called when `dismiss` is subscribed. So if you call `goHome` before that subscription, `dismissObserver` is null by that time and you get the error

Anyway, what you're implementing with `dismiss` and `dismissObserver` is the concept of a `Subject`. Just replace your NavService constructor and `goHome` by:

```
constructor (
  private authService:    AuthService,
  private platform:       Platform
) {
  this.dismiss = new Subject();
}

public goHome():void {
  this.dismiss.next(true);
}
```

and you're fine: You may miss value(s) if your subscription comes after it, but no error is thrown. Try replacing `Subject` by `BehaviorSubject` to cache one value for subscriptions that come after the emission.

EDIT: I forgot to mention you need to `import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';`