# How to use Ionic2 Events

Tags: angular, events, ionic2

I'm getting inconsistent results from the login event created in my Login service.  When the user logs in or logs out the event is not getting picked up on the subscription pages changing the links on the page accordingly.

***UPDATE***
After more testing I've found that each page does pick up on the subscription but only after it has been entered first. In other words if I go to pageWithLink.ts before logging in then the page will correctly read the subscription update but if I login before going to the page it will ignore the subscription update.

tabs.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { page1 } from '../page1';
import { page2 } from '../page2';
import { page3 } from '../page3';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class Tabs {
  index:any;
  tab1Root: any = page1;
  tab2Root: any = page2;
  tab3Root: any = page3;

  constructor(public navParams: NavParams) {
    if(navParams.get('index') === undefined || navParams.get('index') === null){
        this.index = "0";
    } else {
        this.index = navParams.get('index');
    }
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { Tabs } from '../tabs';
import { page1 } from '../page1';
import { page2 } from '../page2';
import { page3 } from '../page3';

import { LoginService } from '../services/loginService';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    page1,
    page2,
    page3,
    Tabs
],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      swipeBackEnabled: true
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    page1,
    page2,
    page3,
    Tabs
],
  providers: [LoginService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

loginService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController, NavController, ViewController, Events, App } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Tabs } from '../tabs';
import { page1 } from '../page1';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  userStatus: boolean;
  constructor(public events:Events, public alertController:AlertController, public navController: NavController, public viewController:ViewController, public app:App){}
  sendUserStatus(statusOfUser) {
    this.events.publish('login:Status', statusOfUser);
  }

  login(){
   //login successful
   this.sendUserStatus(true)
  }

  logout(){
   //logout successful
     this.sendUserStatus(false)
      }
    }
```

pageWithLink.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'pageWithLink',
  templateUrl: 'pageWithLink.html',
  providers: [LoginService]
})
export class pageWithLink {
      person: any;
      constructor(public events:Events){
         this.events.subscribe('login:Status', login => {
         this.person = login;
        })
      }
}
```

pageWithLink.html

```
<ion-header class="opaque">
   <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only *ngIf="person" (click)="signout()">
        <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button ion-button icon-only *ngIf="!person" (click)="openModal()">
        <ion-icon name="log-in"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: `providers: [LoginService]` are you setting it in all linked pages?

Comment: @suraj yes LoginService is set in all linked pages.

Comment: updated the answer.. You should not be trying to use NavCOntroller in an injectable service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@suraj had most of it which led to several other fixes adjustments including:
1) making much of what goes into my constructors private as appropriate
2) what got the fix for me was adding a login in check to each of pages to provide a beginning state in case a user logged in already.

New loginService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController, Events, App } from 'ionic-angular';//don't use NavController or ViewController in Injectables!
import { Tabs } from '../tabs';
import { page1 } from '../page1';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  userStatus: boolean;
  constructor(private events:Events, private alertController:AlertController,  private app:App){}
  sendUserStatus(statusOfUser) {
    this.events.publish('login:Status', statusOfUser);
  }

  login(){
   //login successful
   this.sendUserStatus(true)
  }

  logout(){
   //logout successful
     this.sendUserStatus(false)
      }
    }
```

new pageWithLink.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'pageWithLink',
  templateUrl: 'pageWithLink.html'//no provider for LoginService, that's all in app.module.ts!
})
export class pageWithLink {
      person: any;
      constructor(private events:Events){

  if(UserExists){//this is a condition stating the current login status
    this.person = true;
   }

     this.events.subscribe('login:Status', login => {
     this.person = login;
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set

`providers: [LoginService]`
in **app.module.ts** within ngModule.

Currently you have set LoginService as provider for each page. So a new service is created for every component. For your events to work `LoginService` needs to be singleton.

```
@NgModule({
    //declarations,imports etc.
    providers:[LoginService]
})
```

and remove provider from all other pages.This way only one event is published for the single service and will be picked by every page.
The

> No provider for navcontroller

is because you are injecting Navcontroller into a service.
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833414/ionic2-inject-navcontroller-to-injectable-service) for explanation

Comment: I like your answer and that's what the docs say but when I take the LoginService provider from the other pages, each page gives me the following error: 

Error in ./Tabs class Tabs - caused by: No provider for NavController!

Comment: can you add app.module.ts to question?

Comment: app.module.ts is added. Maybe I'm not implementing the LoginService correctly in other places in the app?

Comment: the navcontroller error is a different one..maybe issue in Tabs.ts

Comment: not very helpful given that your proposed solution causes the error. Do you think we could look into this a little further? the navCtrl and viewCtrl are part of the LoginService. For some reason they are registering errors when the Service is taken as a singleton . . .

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but it does not change the event behavior where I must first go to the page before the event will correctly instantiated updating the link options on the pages based on login status.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to subscribe to `events` of `LoginService` so check by updating  'pageWithLink' as below :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'pageWithLink',
  templateUrl: 'pageWithLink.html',
  providers: [LoginService]
})
export class pageWithLink {
  person: any;
  constructor(private loginService: LoginService){
     this.loginService.events.subscribe('login:Status', login => {
       this.person = login;
     });
  }
}
```