# Ionic 3 redirect from app.component class to another page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I’m getting push notification messages and once I receive the message, I want to redirect to another page or show another page instead of home page.

`NavController` doesn’t work here, so I was wondering what will?

```
export class MyApp{

    rootPage:any = HomePage;

    constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, public push: Push) {

        platform.ready().then(() => {
            // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
            // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
            statusBar.styleDefault();
            splashScreen.hide();
        });


        this.push.rx.notification()
            .subscribe((msg) => {
                alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
                // I want to redirect to another page with msg object instead of HomePage
            });

    }
}
```

Because in app.component.ts under MyApp{}, when I declare `constructor(public navCtrl:nacNavController)` then I get the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for NavController!
Error: No provider for NavController!
    at injectionError (main.js:1509)
    at noProviderError (main.js:1547)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (main.js:3048)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (main.js:3087)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (main.js:3019)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (main.js:2888)
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (main.js:3835)
    at resolveDep (main.js:11202)
    at createClass (main.js:11071)
    at createDirectiveInstance (main.js:10899)
    at injectionError (main.js:1509)
    at noProviderError (main.js:1547)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (main.js:3048)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (main.js:3087)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (main.js:3019)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (main.js:2888)
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (main.js:3835)
    at resolveDep (main.js:11202)
    at createClass (main.js:11071)
    at createDirectiveInstance (main.js:10899)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at o (polyfills.js:3)
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: what do you mean by _NavController doesn’t work here_?

Comment: I mean in app.component.ts, when I use `NavController` then I get  the error 

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for NavController!

Answer (score 6):

You should [read the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-the-root-component)...

> **Navigating from the Root component**
>
> What if you want to control navigation from your root app component? You can't inject `NavController` because any components that are navigation controllers are children of the root component so they aren't available to be injected.
>
> By adding a reference variable to the `ion-nav`, you can use `@ViewChild` to get an instance of the `Nav` component, which is a navigation controller (it extends `NavController`):

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
   template: '<ion-nav #myNav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>'
})
export class MyApp {
   @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController
   public rootPage: any = TabsPage;

   // Wait for the components in MyApp's template to be initialized
   // In this case, we are waiting for the Nav with reference variable of "#myNav"
   ngOnInit() {
      // Let's navigate from TabsPage to Page1
      this.nav.push(Page1);
   }
}
```

So in your case, you just need to check if your `app.component.html` file includes this (please notice the `#myNav` template variable):

```
<ion-nav #myNav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

And then in the component code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

//...
export class MyApp{
    @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController
    rootPage: any = HomePage;

    constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, public push: Push) {

        platform.ready().then(() => {
            // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
            // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
            statusBar.styleDefault();
            splashScreen.hide();
        });


        this.push.rx.notification()
            .subscribe((msg) => {
                alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
                this.nav.push(TheOtherPage); // <- use it here! :)
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted as an answer. Certainly solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped @Loke :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any reason why you can't use the `NavController` like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Push, PushToken } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
import { SomeOtherPage } from '...';

export class HomePage {

  constructor(private push: Push
    public navCtrl: NavController) {
        push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
          return this.push.saveToken(t);
        }).then((t: PushToken) => {
          console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
        });
        this.push.rx.notification().subscribe((msg) => {
          this.navCtrl.push(SomeOtherPage, { msg: msg });
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you read my question, I mentioned `MyApp {}` which is app.component.ts not `HomePage{}` which is home.ts. In app.component.ts, when I use NavController then I get the error Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for NavController!

Comment: Hey Abdul, you've obviously updated the question since I read it because originally you just said you couldn't use NavController, which didn't make sense, I've not encountered your issue before, I'll look a little more closely at it.

Comment: Why not just put the push rx subscription into the Homepage component instead and do the routing from there?