# Ionic - Where to put the html for a global ion-menu component

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I've put the HTML markup for a global side menu in app.html However as you can't seem to inject the NavController into app.components.ts, I can't actually do anything with the menu. So my question is, where on earth are you support to put the code for the ion-menu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 3 redirect from app.component class to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44737708/ionic-3-redirect-from-app-component-class-to-another-page)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve explain and place some code and that will help you